# Does SQL-99+ support an UNNEST operator, and if so, what are its semantics?

Tags: ansi-sql

I can find `UNNEST` mentioned in the [SQL-99 spec](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-99.bnf.html#collection%20derived%20table) under `collection derived table` (I have a copy of the actual spec), but it never defines the semantics of such a construct...

From some further research, I'm just getting more confused. It looks like in SQL-99 (just from the grammar...) it looks like you can't use it in the SELECT list, which leaves me to wonder how you're supposed to actually use it? I guess LATERAL is required?

Comment: Which SQL-99 implementation are you using? Apparently, [PostgreSQL supports it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number).

Comment: I'm looking at the spec itself. I'm working on a related spec